# What does clearing log selection means

Tags: apex, developer-console

While running test class in developer console .
I see a window displaying clearing log selection .
Does it means it is clearing all the logs in the developer console .I wanted to know the exact meaning of it . 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, it does clear the logs from the console, and from memory as well.

Comment: Thanks Rahul ,but  is that needed everytime

Comment: You can mitigate any doubts with this query;
SELECT Count(id) FROM apexlog

Comment: @user75937 its up to you, if needed you can do it, any way you will see the latest logs at the top of the list.